# Select columns value based on logic applied on the rows

Tags: sql, oracle

It is a self-join I need, but I'm having difficulty with this problem and I hope someone can help me.
I have a table with MAT_CODE, MATERIAL and VENDOR and I am trying to generate a new column with NEW_MATCODE as per the below scenario.

Sample Data :

```
NEW_MATCODE     MAT_CODE    MATERIAL        VENDOR      WIN_VENDOR
                            X-043223065     GP002134    GP002134
3065                        X-043223065     USD005      P10011
3065            3065        X-043223065     EUR003      P10011

4567            4567        X-023065        UD00005     UD00005
4567                        X-023065        DF00388     UD00005

4321                        X-04065         P24005      P24005
4321            4321        X-04065         D41111      P24005
4321                        X-04065         D46732      P24005

                            X-0432065       US7800      D0230005
                            X-0432065       EUR234      D067805

123             123         X-04322         P0008       P0008
123             1234        X-04322         EU0323      P0008
123             1262        X-04322         EUR0032     P0008

2345            2345        X-04322         DFGH322     P12008
123456          123456      X-04322         EUR00323    P12008
1113            1113        X-04322         EUR0032     P12008
```

Logic for 1,2 and 3 sets of data:
Pick up the MATERIAL AND WIN_VENDOR combination and get the unique MAT_CODE and apply it across all MATERIAL- WIN_VENDOR combinations as the NEW_MATCODE

Logic for 4th set :
If no combination for MAT_CODE exists then leave it as-is

Logic for 5th set:
When different MAT_CODE exists for the same MATERIAL and WIN_VENDOR combination, apply NEW_MATCODE as the MAT_CODE from MATERIAL - VENDOR where VENDOR = WIN_VENDOR

Logic for 6th set:
When different MAT_CODE exists for the same MATERIAL and WIN_VENDOR combination, and VENDOR <> WIN_VENDOR leave MAT_CODE as-is.

Hope it is clear. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following query will get you most of the way to what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT mat_code, material, vendor, win_vendor, 
       CASE 
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT mat_code) OVER (PARTITION BY material, win_vendor) = 0 THEN mat_code
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT mat_code) OVER (PARTITION BY material, win_vendor) = 1 THEN MAX(mat_code) OVER (PARTITION BY material, win_vendor)
         ELSE NVL((SELECT sub.mat_code FROM material_info sub WHERE sub.material = mi.material AND sub.vendor = sub.win_vendor), mi.mat_code)
       END AS NEW_MAT
FROM material_info mi;
```

The case statement is making use of the analytical functions to handle cases 1-4.  The else branch is attempting to grab Case 5 and if it isn't found defaulting to Case 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot Del.. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Looks like I started getting another issue in here - ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @sdr That would have to be from the select in the else clause.  You could try adding a distinct if multiple rows with the same material, vendor and win_vendor when the vendor = win_vendor should always have the same value.

Comment: I tried this and even this gave me the same error  - ELSE NVL((SELECT DISTINCT sub.mat_code FROM material_info sub WHERE sub.material = mi.material AND sub.vendor = sub.win_vendor), mi.mat_code) Also tried using MAX with partition and no luck

Comment: @sdr If you are OK with the max, I would use the aggregate function instead of the analytical (i.e don't add the over clause)  This will guarantee one result.

Comment: Thanks Del.. That works but unfortunately that is not the full solution.. Here I had 2 scenarios that came up - Duplicates with Mat_code, Material, Vendor and Win_Vendor - This will work with Aggregate function MAX. However for the same Material, Vendor and Win_Vendor combination if I have 2 Mat_Codes then we need to leave it as-is.

Comment: Got it finally :)    Added another CASE CONDITION within NVL --------   ELSE NVL(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT mat_code) OVER (PARTITION BY material, win_vendor,vendor) = 0
       THEN (SELECT MAX(sub.mat_code) FROM material_info sub WHERE sub.material = mi.material AND sub.vendor = sub.win_vendor)
       ELSE mi.mat_code END , mi.mat_code)